# How to force Google Maps API v3 to discard touch support?

Tags: javascript, delphi, google-maps-api-3

I'm using a Delphi component based on the [Chromium Embedded project](http://code.google.com/p/chromiumembedded/). While navigating in a test HTML with some Javascript code to access Google Maps API, it displays the controls for touch enabled devices.

I've seen that this [issue](http://code.google.com/p/chromiumembedded/issues/detail?id=134) is already fixed in the project's svn, but I'm going through hell to compile that stuff.

However, if I go to the maps.google.com website (and not my testing HTML with Javascript), my component will display the controls for a non-touch enabled device.

So, I was wondering... is there a way to force Google Maps v3 API to accept me as a non-touch device?

**EDIT:** added user agent and test case below.

User agent:

```
Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/534.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/12.0.742.53 Safari/534.36
```

Test case:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <style type="text/css">
      html { height: 100% }
      body { height: 100%; margin: 0px; padding: 0px }
      #map_canvas { height: 100% }
    </style>
    <script type="text/javascript"
        src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false&language=pt_BR&region=BR">
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      var map;
      function initialize() {
      var latlng_map = new google.maps.LatLng(-23.510700, -46.602300);
      var myOptions_map = {
      zoom: 15,
      center: latlng_map,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
      };
      map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"),
      myOptions_map);
    }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body onload="initialize()">
    <div id="map_canvas" style="width:100%; height:100%"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you show the code which you are using to load the google map?  Do you check the user agent used by of the Chromium component?

Comment: The current binary release of cef solved the issue discussed in this post, although nobody knows the answer so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Maps API relies on browsers correctly exposing their capabilities (e.g. touch enabled). There is no sane way to force the API to discard touch support.